# Creating numerous instances of the same class side by side

Tags: java, swing, class

How can I place 3 identical instances of the same class side-by-side? In the code below, the 3 are on top of one another - how can I modify this so they are side by side?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RestaurantBillCalculatorMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Correct arguments not provided.\nPlease enter database username and password on the command line.\nProgram will now exit.");
        } else {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setSize(1200, 600);
            mainPanel.setVisible(true);

            RestaurantBillCalculator application1 = new RestaurantBillCalculator(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant", args[0], args[
            application1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            application1.setSize(400, 600);
            application1.setVisible(true);

            RestaurantBillCalculator application2 = new RestaurantBillCalculator(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant", args[0], args[1]);
            application2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            application2.setSize(400, 600);
            application2.setVisible(true);

            RestaurantBillCalculator application3 = new RestaurantBillCalculator(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant", args[0], args[1]);
            application3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            application3.setSize(400, 600);
            application3.setVisible(true);

            mainPanel.add(application1);
            mainPanel.add(application2);
            mainPanel.add(application3);

            frame.add(mainPanel);

        }
    } // end method main
}
```

I'm also getting an error in the code: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container". What is causing this?

Part of the constructor is as follows, I suspect it is something to do with this?

```
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout( null );
```

I am mostly new to Java, so still very much learning.

Comment: Use a [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804603/java-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-addin)

Comment: We were asked to use absolute positioning within each instance, can I use a layout manager for the positioning of each instance?

Comment: Yes, a layout manager would work great, and be a lot more flexible than absolute positioning.

Comment: Your error is happening because you're adding a JFrame to a JPanel. That would be like trying to put cars into people -- bat chit crazy. Solution: don't do this. I can tell you from experience that guessing at this stuff doesn't work, so read the tutorials, don't put JFrames into JPanels but rather JPanels into JFrames.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question about using a Layout Manager, you can try reading through the Java tutorial here: [Swing Group Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html)

Here's some simple starter code to help you get a basic understanding of how to rearrange your components in a single row, horizontally:

```
...
/*
when you add components to the layout, it will 
automatically add them to your mainPanel, so the following is unnecessary.
mainPanel.add(application1);       
mainPanel.add(application2);
mainPanel.add(application3);
*/
frame.add(mainPanel);

GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(mainPanel);
mainPanel.setLayout(layout);

//set margins around components by default
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);    

layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
    .addComponent(application1)
    .addComponent(application2)
    .addComponent(application3));

layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
    .addComponent(application1)
    .addComponent(application2)
    .addComponent(application3));
```

The link above has pictures to better visualize how the layout manager interprets horizontal and vertical groups.

Comment: Why use the complex GroupLayout, a layout manager that is much better suited for code-generation software, than the much easier to handle GridLayout?

Comment: You're right, GridLayout is definitely the best choice here: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys - I've tried adding the above code (as I can understand how it works) but I am still getting the java exception I mentioned above?